# Is the output stream automatically flushed at the end of the program?

Tags: c++, cout, flush

In C++, is the output stream automatically flushed when the program ends? (At the end of the main function).

Comment: Short Answer ("Yes") All streams are flushed when closed, All streams are closed when the program ends.

Comment: What is the long answer?

Comment: I added the additional information. (I"m not your downvote)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info. (I don't really care about downvotes, just here for the information.)